# Find how many numbers between 9,999 and 100,000 do not contain a 0, 1, or 2

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $S$ represent the set of all natural numbers : 9,999 $<$ x < 100,000.

Let $A_i$ represent the set of all numbers in $S$ where no digit in $x$ equals $i$. 
$\\$

For example, $98,766 \in A_i$ but $11,001 \notin A_i$.

(a) $|A_0 | \cup |A_1| \cup |A_2|$

(b) $\overline{ |A_0 | \cup |A_1| \cup |A_2|} $

My solution:

We know that there are a total of 99,999-10,000 = 89,000 numbers in set $S$. And we know all numbers in $S$ are 6-digits long. So I think $|A_0|$ = $9^6$ , but  for $|A_1|$ and $|A_2|= 8*9^5$ because the first digit cannot start with a 0 since the number has to be between the range above.

My problem then becomes how I should count the duplicates. I know ultimately I should use the inclusion exclusion principle to figure out this answer, but I am stuck in figuring out the intersections. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a confusion between the numbers in the title and in the question. Please make the required correction.

Comment: Some simple mistakes: There are 90,000 numbers in your set, and they all have 5 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a direct route, you can just consider that each digit can be one of $(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ and infer that the count of such $5$-digit numbers, given $7$ choices for each location, is $7^5 = 16807$

If the revised range is inclusive - that is, $9999$ is also included in the range - then obviously there is $1$ more to add.

Comment: @stevengregory and why would you do that?

Comment: You're right. I deleted the comment.

Comment: @Joffan I made this much more complicated than I should have. Thank you for the simple explanation!

Comment: I have a question though. Wouldn't 7^5 contain the numbers 33,333-99,999?

Comment: The ones that had only the non-forbidden digits. Numbers like 33340, 33341, 33342 would be excluded.